# QueryTimeoutException: ORA-01653: unable to extend table when used spring-batch

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-batch

When I used spring-batch and oracle, I got such error in logs:

> [8/17/19 11:49:58:730 MSK] 000000c6 SystemOut     O [2019-08-17
>   11:49:58.728] ERROR ngframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep
>   Encountered an error executing step clobStep1 in job clobProcessJob
>   org.hibernate.QueryTimeoutException: ORA-01653: unable to extend table
>   TECH.ORGANIZATIONRECORD by 1024 in tablespace USERS

ORGANIZATIONRECORD - это таблица, в которой производилась миграция данных.

ORA-01653 it's about can't to extends table, but what does it mean?
How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a new datafile for the existing tablespace

```
ALTER TABLESPACE USERS ADD DATAFILE '/u01/oradata/userdata.dbf' SIZE 1000M;
```

Please adjust size of the data file and location of the datafile according to your need.

Cheers!!